# Use same theme for GitHub project pages and user page

Tags: github, plugins, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to get my project pages to display the same theme as my user github page

I am using the gem `jekyll-remote-theme` to achieve this. Followed instructions and added `remote_theme: ad1tyawagh/ad1tyawagh.github.io` to config.yml of the project page.

- Personal github page branch: `master` [link](https://www.github.com/ad1tyawagh/ad1tyawagh.github.io)
- Project github page branch: `gh-pages` (Default for all projects) [link](https://github.com/ad1tyawagh/vcrnn/tree/gh-pages)

The project site is not showing any navigation bar items although my user page is showing them.

My nav items were in a the `_data` folder in a file called `_menu.yml` and copying this folder to project pages’ gh-pages branch fixed the issue, but every time I changed the menu items, I would have to copy the folder to all project pages one by one, which is cumbersome.

`jekyll-remote-theme` requires the remote_theme to have the same file structure like a gem based theme for Jekyll. So, I thought changing the dir of the `_data` folder to assets/data folder ( I also changed the `_config.yml` to include `data_dir: assets/data`. It is `_data` by default) to resemble a gem theme. Nav works on the user page, but not on the project page.

Any more ideas to fix this?